# Thinking about the correct design for technical analysis indicators

Tags: c#, oop, .net-5

I'm using a partial class with extension methods for technical analysis indicators based on `TALib.NETCore` package. I was thinking about what the correct design would've been in this case.

The following must be taken into account:

- unknown amount of arguments/parameters
- they may have more than one overload, just like `Wma`. For ex. `IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv>`, `IReadOnlyList<decimal>`, etc.

TA lib is used by many people and here is someone who've implemented it with an abstract class

- https://github.com/YAlexander/CryptoTrader/blob/master/src/core/Trading/Indicators/BaseIndicator.cs
- https://github.com/YAlexander/CryptoTrader/blob/master/src/core/Trading/Indicators/Mama.cs

What would you suggest?

```cs
public static partial class IndicatorExtensions
{
    private static IReadOnlyList<decimal?> FixIndicatorOrdering(IReadOnlyList<decimal> source, int outBegIdx, int outNbElement)
    {
        var outValues = new List<decimal?>();
        var validItems = source.Take(outNbElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < outBegIdx; i++)
            outValues.Add(null);

        foreach (var value in validItems)
            outValues.Add(value);

        return outValues;
    }
}

public static partial class IndicatorExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<decimal?> MinusDI(this IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> source, int period = 14)
    {
        var diValues = new decimal[source.Count];

        var highs = source.Select(e => e.High).ToArray();
        var lows = source.Select(e => e.Low).ToArray();
        var closes = source.Select(e => e.Close).ToArray();

        var result = TALib.Core.MinusDI(highs, lows, closes, 0, source.Count - 1, diValues, out int outBegIdx, out int outNbElement, period);

        if (result == TALib.Core.RetCode.Success)
        {
            return FixIndicatorOrdering(diValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement);
        }

        throw new InvalidIndicatorCalculationException("Could not calculate DI-.");
    }
}

public class MacdItem
{
    public IReadOnlyList<decimal?> Macd { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<decimal?> Signal { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<decimal?> Histogram { get; set; }
}

public static partial class IndicatorExtensions
{
    public static MacdItem Macd(this IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> source, int fastPeriod = 12, int slowPeriod = 26, int signalPeriod = 9)
    {
        var macdValues = new decimal[source.Count];
        var signalValues = new decimal[source.Count];
        var histValues = new decimal[source.Count];

        var closes = source.Select(e => e.Close).ToArray();

        var result = TALib.Core.Macd(closes, 0, source.Count - 1, macdValues, signalValues, histValues, out int outBegIdx, out int outNbElement, fastPeriod, slowPeriod, signalPeriod);

        if (result == TALib.Core.RetCode.Success)
        {
            return new MacdItem
            {
                Macd = FixIndicatorOrdering(macdValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement),
                Signal = FixIndicatorOrdering(signalValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement),
                Histogram = FixIndicatorOrdering(histValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement)
            };
        }

        throw new InvalidIndicatorCalculationException("Could not calculate MACD.");
    }
}

public static partial class IndicatorExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<decimal?> Wma(this IReadOnlyList<Ohlcv> source, int period = 30, CandleVariable type = CandleVariable.Close)
    {
        var wmaValues = new decimal[source.Count];

        var closes = type switch
        {
            CandleVariable.Open => source.Select(e => e.Open).ToArray(),
            CandleVariable.Low => source.Select(e => e.Low).ToArray(),
            CandleVariable.High => source.Select(e => e.High).ToArray(),
            _ => source.Select(e => e.Close).ToArray(),
        };

        var result = TALib.Core.Wma(closes, 0, source.Count - 1, wmaValues, out int outBegIdx, out int outNbElement, period);

        if (result == TALib.Core.RetCode.Success)
        {
            return FixIndicatorOrdering(wmaValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement);
        }

        throw new InvalidIndicatorCalculationException("Could not calculate WMA.");
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<decimal?> Wma(this IReadOnlyList<decimal> source, int period = 30)
    {
        var wmaValues = new decimal[source.Count];

        var result = TALib.Core.Wma(source.ToArray(), 0, source.Count - 1, wmaValues, out int outBegIdx, out int outNbElement, period);

        if (result == TALib.Core.RetCode.Success)
        {
            return FixIndicatorOrdering(wmaValues.ToList(), outBegIdx, outNbElement);
        }

        throw new InvalidIndicatorCalculationException("Could not calculate WMA.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t help you with TA-Lib, I gave up on it a long time ago because it’s based on 30 year old code.  If you want a more modern library, try [Stock.Indicators](https://daveskender.github.io/Stock.Indicators) for .NET.